# What is the best way to externalize the static items used in iOS app?

Tags: ios, property-list

I am working on app where I have country object and I will be having around 200 instances of object. Each object will have few properties like flagName, capitalCity etc.. I started working on prototype using only 10 countries and I stored these objects inside the viewDidLoad method as an arrays. I know its not a good practice to "hard code" everything in the source code. In a real app, I would like to externalize these static items and put them in a file or database or somewhere else. What is the best way to store such information ? I am thinking of property list but  if the data-model changes then I will have to re-submit the app. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use a plist if you always need all objects in memory at once. Use a database (sqlite or core-data) if you only need a few objects at a time.

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev No, do not use `NSUserDefaults` to store data.

Comment: @rmaddy well, should it be database then?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load a JSON file from your web site. Create a simple JSON model, hide the file on your web site and have the app load it from there. If you want to change it, you just have to change the JSON file on your server. This way you won't have to re-submit the app.

Cache the content of the file in your app so it can work off line, if needed.

Just a suggestion.